# android phonegap Design

Tags: android, cordova

I have designed my **phonegap** android application using html and
css.
So i want to know how to get
the same design size in all the mobiles.Is there any settings
available.Please tell me the solution.
Thanks in Advance.

**update**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <style>
            /* App custom styles */
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
    </head>

<style>
     #searchwrapper {
width:90%; 
height:48px;
background-image:url(../images/input-box.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-size: 100% 100%;
margin-left:15px;
position:relative; 
}

.searchbox {
border:0px; 
background-color:transparent; 
position:absolute; 
top:4px;
left:9px;
width:86%;
height:34px;
}

.searchbox_submit {
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border:0px; 
background-color:transparent; 
position:absolute; 
top:4px;
left:90%;
width:9%;
height:40px;
}

 #searchwrapperIC {
width:90%; 
height:48px;
background-image:url(../images/input-box.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-size: 100% 100%;
margin-left:15px;
position:relative; 
}

.searchboxIC {
border:0px; 
background-color:transparent; 
position:absolute; 
top:4px;
left:9px;
width:86%;
height:34px;
}

.searchbox_submitIC {
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border:0px; 
background-color:transparent; 
position:absolute; 
top:4px;
left:90%;
width:9%;
height:40px;
}
body {
font-family:Arial,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;
font-size: 0.8em;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
#loadingScreen {
background: url(../images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat 5px 8px;
padding-left: 25px;
}
/* hide the close x on the loading screen */
.loadingScreenWindow .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
display: none;
}
.checkBox
{
        background-position: 0px 0px;
}
    .checkBoxClear
{
        background-position: -32px 0px;
}
    .checkBox, .checkBoxClear
{
        background-image: url('../images/CheckBox2.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        cursor: hand;
}
</style>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1" style="background-color:white">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">

              <img src="images/header-search-causes.png" alt="image" style="width:100%" />

            </div>
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 16px">
            <br>    
    <label style="font-size:12pt" align="center">Choose one of the following options to search our directory of causes</label></td>
  <br/>

        <div id="searchwrapper" style="width:90%;"align="center">
            <input type="text" class="searchbox" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search" />
            <img src="images/search-button.png" alt="image" class="searchbox_submitIC" />

        </div>
      <br/>
                <li style="list-style:none" data-theme="b">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slidefade">Button</a><br/>
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slidefade">Button</a><br/>
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slidefade">Button</a><br/>
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slidefade">Button</a><br/>

                    </li>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:4%;border-width:3px;padding-top:2%;background-color:#00458D;" align="center" data-theme="#00458D" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

                <table width=100%>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr>
                <img src="images/Home.PNG" alt="image" style="width:20%;height:6%;" />
                 <img src="images/messages-menu.jpg" alt="image" style="width:20%;height:6%;" />
                 <img src="images/settings-menu.jpg" alt="image" style="width:20%;height:6%;" />
                 <img src="images/close-menu.png" alt="image" style="width:20%;height:6%;" />

                 </tr>
                 </table>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            //App custom javascript
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing Without JQuery mobile you have to do the dynamic layout sizes to the content like

- You have to use percentage for height and width
- Make the style to html body position relative
- And give style position absolute to the inner body element

Note: Designing Layout using jquery mobile framework is very easy to make a good and rich layout. And you dont need to bother about the Various mobile sizes. It can manage automatically.

Comment: just make fixed footer for the input field pages. Virtual keyboard makes footer jumping.